# Why does Gradle not look in the local maven repository for plugins?

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

I have built a Gradle plugin and published it to the local maven repository. I can see it in my ~/.m2/repository. However, when I run a Gradle project to use this plugin, it does not even look in the local repository...at least, not based on the output.

It reports this when running from the command-line:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where: Build file 'D:\Work\MuseProject\update4j-gradle-plugin\example\build.gradle'
>   line: 15
>
> What went wrong: Plugin [id: 'net.christophermerrill.gradle.update4j', version: '0.1'] was not
>   found in any of the following sources:
>
> -- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
>
> -- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'net.christophermerrill.gradle.update4j:net.christophermerrill.gradle.update4j.gradle.plugin:0.1')
>
> Searched in the following repositories:
>       Gradle Central Plugin Repository

I have added mavenLocal() to the buildscript configuration. I also tried adding the specific dependency (as was suggested elsewhere) with no effect

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'net.christophermerrill:update4j-gradle-plugin:0.1'
  }
}
```

Best I can tell from the output, it is not even looking in the local repository, but I am not 100% sure. Using the --scan and --info options does not provide any additional insights - they appear to do nothing at all, which I suspect is because the failure appears before the plugins finish loading (just guessing).

Is there a way to determine if Gradle is looking in the local Maven repo? I am trying to eliminate this as a possibility. The alternative, of course, is that my plugin is not published correctly. That will be my next question, after I settle this one :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think that specifying a [custom plugin repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories) looks promising: this feature lets you configure the `plugins{}` DSL to resolve from other repositories in addition to the gradle plugin portal. I think you'd want to update your `settings.gradle` with configuration something along the lines of:

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      gradlePluginPortal()
  }
}
```

(Note that this code block needs to appear at the top of `settings.gradle`).

Comment: Thanks!!  That was exactly the solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for  me :/

Comment: @JohnLaBarge - sorry for the delay; can you elaborate? Have you ensured that this block is the first thing at the top of `settings.gradle`?

Comment: It's not working for me too.
this block is the first thing at the top of settings.gradle.
Don't know what is the cause

Comment: @TheD3luxed - one thing, if you're using Kotlin vs. Groovy, the format is different (I can update answer if that's your situation)

Comment: I found a solution. I needed to set proxy for dependencies declared in build.gradle inside buildSrc. I had to create new settings.gradle file in buildSrc directory.

Comment: Strange this does not work for buildSrc......it does not resolve plugins with the repostiories specified in pluginManagement ....